# Does destiny affect the type of loot you get in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Does destiny change the loot you get?  If you take sorcery destiny will that make it so most items you get in the game world are weapons/armors mages use, or if you choose finesse destiny would it make it so that you mostly get finesse weapons/armors?

I am playing as pure warrior at the moment and most items I find in chests or dead bodies are warrior weapons (Greatswords,Longswords,Hammers) and warrior armors.  I do get items for other "classes" but not as much/often as warrior items.

Comment: My experience suggests no relation whatsoever - as purely sorcery, I've found more great set might and finesse items than I can shake a stick at (and only two set sorcery items). I sell/salvage all of it, but I definitely find more non-sorcery than sorcery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not from my experience.  The loot drops appear to be random, and not impacted by your choice of skills or destiny.  I have no points in Might, yet I find heavy armor, swords, and hammers with alarming regularity.

I ran a test with my "current" destiny, which is Finesse/Sorcery, and before filling my inventory I found:

- 9 Sorcery items
- 11 Might items
- 14 Finesse items

(along with other assorted junk)

I then changed my Destiny to the default level 1 Might destiny, and went forth and looted again, and I came away with:

- 7 Sorcery items
- 10 Might items
- 8 Finesse items

If destiny played a significant role in determining loot drops, I'd expect to see a much larger bias towards Sorcery/Finesse in the first category, and Might in the second.  As it was, I found roughly similar amounts of items from each category, regardless of my destiny.  This is not an exhaustive test, and probably a much larger sample size could be taken, but I think this is at least somewhat representative of a random loot drop system.

Do note that even if you have a weapon or piece of armor that you can't use due to your skill choices, you can still break it down at a blacksmith workbench to recover components you *can* use to build armor or weapons for your chosen skill tree.  Not all components will be reusable in other items, but more often than not you'll find something you can use.

Also, since you can respec at any time, if you find something overpowered that's not for your chosen class, you can stick it in your stash in case you decide to re-roll later.

Comment: I just made a new character and I'm playing as a rogue now,and i have to say i keep getting rogue weapons and armors non-stop and almost nothing else,just like i was getting warrior items most of the time when i was playing warrior.This makes me doubt in your answer,because from my experience it seems that destiny really does affect the loot you get.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ, I gathered some empirical data and added it to my answer.  I don't see a statistically significant difference in the type of loot I find depending on my destiny over a sample size of about 60 "attribute point dependent" items.  You can feel free to run a larger sample size if you so desire, I'd be interested to see the results.

Comment: I guess i am just ridiculously lucky because i tend to get just the gear for the class i need on both warrior and rogue.I might do a test by making more characters later and having them use different destiny.I also have a friend who mostly gets items for his class on both of his characters (he haves mage and rogue) so that is interesting as we both seem to get same results,which really makes me wonder are we both just lucky or what.I think the only way of finding out the truth would be to ask game developers thought.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ, or I could just be ridiculously unlucky :)  That's kind of the problem with a potentially random sequence - you can't really tell whether or not what you're getting is truly random without a gigantic sample size.

Answer (score 0):

i dont believe this is the case, on my char that has never been specced into anything else then finesse (and only finese destiny cards) i keep finding lots of epic might weapons and lots of those magic boomerang things, while i have only found 1 epic feablade's (@ low level)

Comment: Ouch,you're really not lucky then.I made new character like 2 days ago (playing him as pure finesse) and most of the purple and gold items i got so far were for finesse and only few of them for might/sorcery.I guess it's not destiny that changes the loot after all,it's just my awesome luck.